# Why is this Javascript/Ajax function using a random number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, random

I'm helping maintain a Javascript-based web site that was written by someone else.  In their Javascript code, I came across this function, which downloads a file from the specified URL and calls a callback when the download is complete:

```
// ajax wrapper
function getServerData(command, command_label, success_callback)
{
   $.ajax({
     url: command,
     type: 'POST',
     data: { rand: (Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)) },
     success: function(data) { success_callback(data); },
     error: function(error) {if (handleError(error, command_label)) {getServerData(command, command_label, success_callback);}}
   });
}
```

The above makes sense to me, except for this line:

```
     data: { rand: (Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)) },
```

Why is there a random number assigned to the data attribute?  Is this some attempt to defeat a cacheing mechanism, that will fail to work about 0.1% of the time?  Or is it a copy-and-paste-from-an-example detail that wasn't removed even though it's no longer relevant?  Or has it some other (even more obscure) purpose?

Simply removing that line doesn't seem to hurt anything, but I'm worried about removing code whose purpose I don't understand.

Comment: Without seeing a lot more code, and specifically the code on the *server*, it's impossible to say.

Comment: The web server, in this case, is just a dumb/vanilla match-the-URL-to-the-filesystem-and-send-the-requested-file-to-the-client web server.  In particular, it has no knowledge of 'data'.

Comment: The `data` parameter to `$.ajax()` sets up the parameters delivered to the server. The server probably *does* know about it.

Comment: Well, I wrote the web server it's connecting to, and I grepped its source code just now just to double-check that I hadn't written something and latter forgotten it... so if the server does know about it, then it's awfully subtle :)

Comment: Well it may be that somebody was trying to supply a nonce to defeat browser caching, but because it's a POST request that's useless anyway. There are several reasons to send a random nonce to a server, but if the server pays no attention it's probably just an artifact of somebody being confused.